# Multiple Set-Cookie headers ignored by API Gateway in combination with Lambda integration and CloudFront

Tags: aws-lambda, http-headers, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

My setup looks like this:

```
|––––––––––––|                  |–––––––––––––|     |–––––––––––––––––|
|            |  <- origin 1 ->  | API Gateway | <-> | Lambda function |
|            |                  |–––––––––––––|     |–––––––––––––––––|
| CloudFront |  
|            |                  |–––––––––––––|
|            |  <- origin 2 ->  |  S3 bucket  |
|––––––––––––|                  |–––––––––––––|
```

I need CloudFront in front of the API Gateway to get automatic http->https redirection.
I'm using a custom `login.example.com` subdomain w/ CloudFront.
API Gateway's generated URL is the origin 1 for CloudFront distribution.

This all works as expected.

I can even return one `Set-Cookie` header from the lambda function and it will get passed on until it reaches the browser.

```json
{
  "statusCode": 302,
  "body": "",
  "headers": {
    "location": "/test",
    "surrogate-control": "no-store",
    "cache-control": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "expires": "0",
    "content-length": "0",
    "date": "Fri, 19 Feb 2021 17:25:56 GMT",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "set-cookie": "cookie1=68abcdbefbef7d84c26e68; Max-Age=2592000; Domain=example.com; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict"
  },
  "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

Adding another one isn't working - as expected when you look at the docs:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#apigateway-multivalue-headers-and-parameters
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/support-for-multi-value-parameters-in-amazon-api-gateway/

```json
{
  "statusCode": 302,
  "headers": {
    "location": "/test",
    "set-cookie": [
      "cookie1=68abcdbefbef7d84c26e68; Max-Age=2592000; Domain=example.com; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict",
      "cookie2-login=; Max-Age=0; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure"
    ],
    "surrogate-control": "no-store",
    "cache-control": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "expires": "0",
    "content-length": "0"
  }
}
```

Both of these will be ignored/removed.

But even when I'm using the `multiValueHeaders` object to return more than one of the same kind like this:

```json
{
  "statusCode": 302,
  "body": "",
  "headers": {
    "location": "/test",
    "surrogate-control": "no-store",
    "cache-control": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "expires": "0",
    "content-length": "0",
    "date": "Fri, 19 Feb 2021 17:25:56 GMT",
    "connection": "keep-alive"
  },
  "isBase64Encoded": false,
  "multiValueHeaders": {
    "Set-Cookie": [
      "cookie1=68abcdbefbef7d84c26e68; Max-Age=2592000; Domain=example.com; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict",
      "cookie2-login=; Max-Age=0; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure"
    ]
  }
}
```

the API Gateway removes/ignores them from the response it passes on to CloudFront.

What am I doing wrong?
Do I have to map something in the API Gateway when using the `multiValueHeaders`?
Normal `headers['set-cookie']` is passed on automatically but `multiValueHeaders` not?
Are the additional attributes a problem?
Is it a problem that I'm trying to set the cookie for the root-domain and not the login.example.com domain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure how Philipp missed this, as it was on the same page he cited:

> To customize the response, your Lambda function should return a response with the following format.

```json
{
    "cookies" : ["cookie1", "cookie2"],
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headername": "headervalue", ... },
    "body": "Hello from Lambda!"
}
```

So just return `cookies: ['name=value', 'name=value']`

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html#http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.v2

Comment: will definitely check that out ... thanks

Comment: Yes, this works well for me. Thanks!

Comment: This works, thanks. Be sure to use API Gateway V2. For example, for Typescript use package `@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha` and `@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-integrations-alpha` (`alpha` is at the time of writing)

Answer (score 4):

Finally found the answer myself:

The new payload format (2.0) does not support `multiValueHeaders`.

> **Working with AWS Lambda proxy integrations for HTTP APIs**
>
> [...] Format 2.0 doesn't have multiValueHeaders or multiValueQueryStringParameters fields. Duplicate headers are combined with commas and included in the headers field. Duplicate query strings are combined with commas and included in the queryStringParameters field. [...]
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html

So I'm rewriting the `set-cookie` headers to different spellings:

```
Set-cookie
sEt-cookie
seT-cookie
```

That was the way you had to do it before there were `multiValueHeaders` - but it seems it is still the only when you're using the new payload format :(

Comment: Hey Philipp, I thought you'd like to know it's possible to just set a `cookies` array in the response. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

So I'm rewriting the set-cookie headers to different spellings:

Set-cookie

sEt-cookie

seT-cookie

this worked for me, thank you phillip